# What's causing this FatalErrorException?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5.1

I'm new in Laravel 5.1 Can you help me to solving this error because I've  been working on this for whole day and I cannot solve it.

> FatalErrorException in FileEntryController.php line 48: Call to
>   undefined method App\Http\Requests\UploadFiles::save()

Here's my controller :

```
public function index()
{
    $entries = Fileentry::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
    return view('fileentries.index', compact('entries'));
}


public function store(UploadFiles $filename)
{
      if($filename->file('filefield')) {
      $file = $filename->file('filefield');

      $entry = new UploadFiles();

      $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $entry->filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

      $entry->mime = $file->getClientMimeType();
      $entry->original_filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
      $entry->description = Request::input('description');
      $entry->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

      $entry->save();


      $file->move(Storage::disk('local')->put($file->getFilename().'.'.$extension,  File::get($file)));

      return redirect('upload');

       }
}
```

And here is my `Request/UploadFiles.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class UploadFiles extends Request
{
/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'filename' => 'mimes:pdf,doc,jpeg,png,docx',
        'description' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Does class UploadFiles or Request have `save` function?

Comment: what do you mean `save` function?...:D i dont have it in my UploadFiles ^^

Comment: but you are calling it on UploadFiles ...

Comment: This makes no sense: $entry = new UploadFiles();   shouldn't it be $entry = new Fileentry(); ( assuming this is your model name )

Comment: Hello @LoucelleEmperio, may I recommend reading more about Laravel? You are missing key important facts. For instance you assign your Request attributes to your Model attributes, then save() the model. You cannot save a Request directly.

Comment: hello hmm... i'm just trying it the `UploadFiles` but i have a model `Fileentry` but it cannot get what my `rules()` have. It still upload other files like `.php` , `.env` , `.html` etch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will not work as expected, and some parts of it should be removed.
First in your `store()` method, you have already imported `UploadedFiles` instance. From your code, I see `UploadedFiles` is a Request class, so this is fine.

However, you should not make another `UploadedFiles` instance, within the `store` method, as this does not make sense.

You should however make a new Model called (`File`) for instance, and you code should be something like below.

public function store(UploadFiles $filename)
{
      if($filename->file('filefield')) {
      $file = $filename->file('filefield');

```
  $entry = new Files();

  $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $entry->filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

  $entry->mime = $file->getClientMimeType();
  $entry->original_filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
  $entry->description = Request::input('description');
  $entry->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

  $entry->save();


  $file->move(Storage::disk('local')->put($file->getFilename().'.'.$extension,  File::get($file)));

  return redirect('upload');

   }
```

}

Comment: yes sir i did that but my Model `Fileentry` has `rules()` but it still upload the files that are not included to my model class T_T. It still upload the `.php` , `.html` etc.

Comment: Probably your rule is not matching a correct HTML field. What is the name of upload file field in the HTML?